# Quran Ayahs Cross referenced

Tags: quran

Is there a database or study where Quran ayahs are cross referenced? (I would be very surprised if not, as that be an infinitely useful way to study and understand Quran.)

Comment: There are tafiseer books where the author primarily tries to explain a verse by an other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no such a thing like softwares or databases and interested people can go through Tafseer books.

Tafseer Al-Mizan authored by Allamah Muhammad Hussein Tabatabai is one of most notable of them.

But some books, named Kashf-u-al-ayat (`کشف الآیات`) (discovering the verses), can be used for this purpose. In fact, they have indices that you can find verses from roots of words.